# Field with variable length for ISO8583 using jPOS

Tags: iso8583, jpos

I am using jPOS for creating ISO8583 message, I am using the genericpackager but it seems it only support data fields of fixed length. I want to prepend the length of the field before the field if it has a variable size.
I am using below:

```
<isofield
  id="34"
  length="32"
  name="Extended Primary Account Number"
  class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
```

and in .java file`isoMsg.set(34, "12345ABCDE");`

What change do I need to make to prepend the length of the field before the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each isofield - you need to modify the class to match the requirements for the appropriate field configuration.

http://jpos.org/doc/javadoc/org/jpos/iso/packager/GenericPackager.html

For instance you can use any of the isofield classes with a Length indicator (L)
such as:

```
class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
```

Or

```
class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLNUM"/>
```

to support a variable length field.

Where the first example is ASCII 2 byte Length and the second one is Binary 2 byte Length.

you can find a list of sample generic packagers here: https://github.com/jpos/jPOS/tree/master/jpos/src/dist/cfg/packager

you can find a list of isofield classes (start with IF_)  here: https://github.com/jpos/jPOS/tree/master/jpos/src/main/java/org/jpos/iso